# IOMeter has filled my drive, but there's no imbw.tst file

Tags: ssd

I ran IOMeter on my new Kingston SSDNow V300 drive to assess the actual disk performance, and now that the test is done I'm left with 2.6GB storage remaining. There's no `iobw.tst` in the root of the drive, as I've read that there would normally be to cause this, so I'm a bit concerned as to whether-or-not I'll need to reformat what is currently my OS drive.

How do I get my 80GB+ storage space back?

**Edit**: Open Command Prompt in Administrator mode and running `del C:\imbw.tst` returns the following error: `Could not find C:\imbw.tst`

Comment: What OS?  Try Running a disk cleanup: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-7

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro x64. I've already tried doing a cleanup through both Windows, and deleting the drive's free space via Ccleaner, neither of which worked. I also tried to defrag the drive which also didn't work.

Comment: IOMeter by default will fill up the entire drive space. You can limit that though by setting the sector size and cordon off only a small part for IOMeter to test.

Comment: That's too little too late, since now the deed is done. I need to know how to get the 80GB+ that it filled back.

Comment: If this is your OS drive, can you be certain that the space hasn't been consumed by something else?  Give windirstat a try to get a visual map of where the space is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IOMeter uses a different place to store the iobw.tst file. In my case on Windows 7 that is the following folder:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore
```

Run the following command in a command prompt to delete the file:

```
del %appdata%\..\Local\VirtualStore\iobw.tst
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running this from a command prompt: `del /S iobw.tst`